# Display a MsgBox if no record found to run a report

Tags: vba, ms-access

The report is initiated from a Form "F_SachberbeiterUnterlagen", which uses a ComboList to search for the name of a specialist in a Table named "Abgabe_Unterlagen"
If the name is found the report is initiated displaying all records for the Specialist.

To avoid empty reports I'd like to display a MsgBox when no record for the Specialist exists.
My code doesn't work I tried different versions already.

can anyone help ?

```
Private Sub SachBearbeiterBericht_Click()
Me.Filter = "Sachbearbeiter_ID_F = " & Me.SachbearbeiterSuche
Me.FilterOn = True
If Not NULL Me.Filter Then
' Record found, proceed with generating the report
 DoCmd.OpenReport "R_MandantZuSachbearbeiter", acPreview, , "Sachbearbeiter_ID_F = " &         Me.SachbearbeiterSuche
Else
' No Record found display MsgBox
MsgBox "Der Bericht enthält keine Daten.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Keine Daten"
End If

End Sub"
```

My code doesn't work I tried different versions already.

```
    Private Sub SachBearbeiterBericht_Click()
    Me.Filter = "Sachbearbeiter_ID_F = " & Me.SachbearbeiterSuche
    Me.FilterOn = True
    If Not NULL Me.Filter Then
    ' Record found, proceed with generating the report
    DoCmd.OpenReport "R_MandantZuSachbearbeiter", acPreview,,"Sachbearbeiter_ID_F = " &         Me.SachbearbeiterSuche
    Else
    ' No Record found display MsgBox
    MsgBox "Der Bericht enthält keine Daten.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Keine Daten"
    End If

    End Sub"
```

To avoid empty reports I'd like to display a MsgBox when no record for the Specialist exists.

Comment: Hello Kostas, thank you for response... however, I don't know where to put this in my code

Comment: The `NoData` event might not be exactly what you need since it will still display the empty report and you can only cancel the printing. Use the `DCount` or `FindFirst` to see if records exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple `DCount` to see if any records exists prior to opening the report.

Not sure about the type of the `Sachbearbeiter_ID_F` field, but if it's text, its value needs to be enclosed in single quotes `' '`.

```
Private Sub SachBearbeiterBericht_Click()

    'No record selected
    If IsNull(Me.SachbearbeiterSuche) Then
        MsgBox "Please select a value"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'No records found
    If DCount("*", "Abgabe_Unterlagen", "Sachbearbeiter_ID_F = " & Me.SachbearbeiterSuche) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Records found
    DoCmd.OpenReport ...
End Sub
```

Also, this syntax is incorrect (among other issues):

```
If Not NULL Me.Filter Then
```

Comment: Ran into one more issue...since there is no data in the "Me.SachbearbeiterSuche" when the form opens, - getting an error if someone clicks "run the report" without selecting any data ...
Is there a way to load data from a query to the field when the form opens ?

Comment: See edit. Check if value selected first.

Comment: great thank you so much, you're making my day...:-) one more question if you don't mind... if I am trying to add the specialist name from the Combobox to the MsgBox message 
"MsgBox "Keine neuen Unterlagen für Sachbearbeiter " & Me.SachbearbeiterSuche"
Im getting the Number vers. the name of the specialist as it's the seconday Index, is there a way to display the name also ?

Comment: I dont see an issue with this: `MsgBox "Keine neuen Unterlagen für Sachbearbeiter " & Me.SachbearbeiterSuche`. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Well yes, as I'm only getting the Index Number displayed vers. the real name

Comment: Looks like it's a multi-column combobox. Use `Me.SachbearbeiterSuche.Column(1)` or which ever column number the name is stored. Also, see the link I posted above and accept the answer if your problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your help...
v/r
Banyan

Comment: Sorry I can't see where to click to accept...?